# Angular JS > ng-disabled directive not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to disable some tabs with condition but **ng-disabled="true"** not working properly.. Even it's not working with 'true' condition

```html
<div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
    <span class="col-md-12 tab-item"
          ng-class="{'tab-active': selectedtab == 'Date'}"
          ng-click="tebSelect('Date')"
          ng-disabled="true">Date</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Its will work with form element. Not html tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-disabled attribute is only working for input, select or button. Try to use ng-class attribute.

when the Example_Value variable is true 'disabled' class will add to element.

ng-class="{ 'disabled': Example_Value == true }"

Answer (score 1):

`ng-disabled` directive adds `disabled` attribute based on expression passed to it and `disabled` attribute only works on form elements like `input`,`select` or `button` elements. Currently you're trying to put `ng-disabled` directive on `span` element which is not going to work in any sense.

The functionality you're trying to achieve is easily possible using `uib-tabs` on AngularJS `ui-bootstrap`, something like below. There you can use `disabled` directive with `uib-tabs` directive, which will help you to disabled tab.

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="$index+1" 
     ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="Tab 1" disable="tab.disabled">
      {{tab.content}}
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" select="alertMe()">
      <uib-tab-heading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </uib-tab-heading>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

[Angular UI Bootstrap tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs)

Comment: Yes.. You are correct.. it's working after I replace span with a button..